# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: selfHook.call is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

I am using `Vue-Multiple Select` package for Multiple Select Options.

https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started

After following their instruction I am getting an Error.

[image]

Very Unknown Error to me.
What I have missed?!

Comment: That error message appears to be from Vue 3, not Vue 2.

Comment: Yes. You are right. :-)

Comment: My point being that Vue-multiselect hasn't been migrated to Vue 3 yet.

Comment: Oh. Very sad. Then which one I can use?

Comment: Vue 3 hasn't even been released yet, it's still in RC. Very few libraries have been migrated. If you need libraries now you'll need to use Vue 2.

Comment: I am confused about Vue version or Vue-Cli version?

Comment: I am not using Vue3. It's in Vue 2.

Comment: for future visitor you can try this...  https://github.com/vueform/multiselect

Answer (score 0):

i Don't know is it right or wrong but you can delete vue-performance extension..This is a workaround for me  and then check.If it still remain you can tell me i will delete the answere....

Comment: Ohh...Its just worked for me sometimes...Hope you will get your correct ans or solve your issue

Comment: I don't know what was wrong. I installed it. Now, No Problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the problem. If hooks are used as property instead of functions.

Bug generated:

```
const VerificaSezioniConfig = {
    delimiters:['[[',']]'],
    data(){
        return{
            sezioni:[1,2]
        }
    },
    mounted:{}
}
```

No Bug:

```
const VerificaSezioniConfig = {
    delimiters:['[[',']]'],
    data(){
        return{
            sezioni:[1,2]
        }
    },
    mounted(){}
}
```